# python (Logging) arquivo de log diario

Tags: python

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para que crie um arquivo de log para cada dia. Atualmente salva em um arquivo só.

```
log_file = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)),"Log.txt")
logging.basicConfig(filename= log_file, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s => %(message)s')
```

Desde já agradeço a colaboração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta alterar o nome do arquivo de `Log.txt` para a data atual:

```
from datetime import date

log_file = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), f"{date.today()}.txt")
```

A função `date.today()` retornará a data atual no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, ficando, assim, os logs salvos em 2019-03-18.txt, por exemplo.

Comment: salvou com o nome {date.today()}.txt, qual alteração sugere que eu faça?!, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você utilizou o prefixo `f` indicando que é uma *f-string*? `f"{date.today()}.txt"`

Comment: Agora deu certo, acho que é a versão que não estava aceitando o f-string, usei `log_file = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "{}.txt".format(date.today()))` e funcionou, obrigada :)

Comment: Ah, sim. As *f-strings* só estão disponíveis nas versões 3.6+ do Python.